SqlDependency: how to work with memory-optimized tables?
I run my C# app using SqlDependency with a query
select productid, productname from dbo.products and it works.
But when I have changed the query to
select productid, productname 
from dbo.productsMO

where ProductsMO is memory-optimized table, then I do not receive notifications. What is the reason? How to work with MO tables?
Or is there another framework to work with memory-optimized tables?
The sample code:
static void Main()
{
    // Remove any existing dependency connection, then create a new one.
    SqlDependency.Stop(ConnectionString);
    SqlDependency.Start(ConnectionString);

    using (SqlConnection connection = CreateConnection())
    using (_command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        // the base table - it works
        //_command.CommandText = "SELECT ProductId, ProductName, ProductDesc FROM dbo.Products";

        // the MO table - no notifications
        _command.CommandText = "SELECT ProductId, ProductName, ProductDesc FROM dbo.ProductsMO";

        // Initial call:  start query notifications:
        RefreshFromDB();

        // Wait and let dependency_OnChange handle SQL notifications until the user decides to exit:
        Console.WriteLine("Press [Return] to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();

        SqlDependency.Stop(ConnectionString);
    }
}

static void RefreshFromDB()
{
    // Make sure the SqlCommand does not already have
    // a notification object associated with it.
    _command.Notification = null;

    // Create and bind the SqlDependency object to the command object.
    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(_command);
    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(SqlDependency_OnChange);

    using (DataTable productTable = new DataTable())
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(_command))
    {
        productTable.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        adapter.Fill(productTable);
// here is code to process...

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("Change Nodification");
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Event handler for SQL notifications.
/// </summary>
static void SqlDependency_OnChange(Object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    SqlDependency dependency = sender as SqlDependency;
    dependency.OnChange -= SqlDependency_OnChange;
    RefreshFromDB();
}


Unsupported SQL Server Features for In-Memory OLTP - there are many limitations. Change tracking, CDC and Event Notification are not supported.

Perhaps you can have a trigger that populates regular table and use notifications on that.

@AlexanderPetrov what is interesting:  the SqlDependency documentation contains chapter about limitations but nothing about in-memory.
